# C# Script task in SSIS - Parsing a DateTime to get the hrs and mins and convert to an integer

Tags: c#, datetime, ssis, integer

I am currently checking the current date and time against the date and time appended to the end of a file name.  I need to check the timing difference between the current time and the time at the end of the filename in order to see if there is greater than an hours difference between the two.

I need to Parse the hh:mm from the currenctTime variable, convert it to an int and compare it to the creationTime variable. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
string FileLocation = Dts.Variables["User::SAPGLDir"].Value.ToString();
string hrDifference = Dts.Variables["User::hrDifference"].Value.ToString();
bool lateFileInFolder = (bool)Dts.Variables["User::lateFileInFolder"].Value;
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

try
{
    // get a list of all the files in the SAPGLDir
    string[] inputFileList = Directory.GetFiles(@FileLocation);

    //default state of boolean 
    lateFileInFolder = false;

    //if there are files in the folder the do the following steps
    if (inputFileList.Length > 0)
    {
        //foreach file name in the directory
        foreach (string inputFileName in inputFileList)
        {
            //selecting the hour from the filename
            string creationTime = inputFileName.Substring(24, 4);

            //if for any file in the folder that the difference in time is greater than the hrDifference then set boolean lateFileInFolder = true
            if ( )
            {
                lateFileInFolder = true;
            }

            //MessageBox.Show(inputFileName.ToString() + " " + creationHour.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Comment: if you want to convert the `currentTime` variable to an Integer then do a google search on `Ticks` or you can convert the current time to an integer by doing the following `long n = long.Parse(currentTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));`

Comment: you are missing some key information on how to solve.  Such as what is the format of the filenames? You are always taking the same substring will filename always be that length?  What about crossing of dates e.g. 11 PM one night to 1 AM next morning?  Could you just use the File Created or Altered time to get what you want and use system.io.FileInfo?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to avoid script task in ssis. I learned it in my working experience with ssis.

Script task is sometimes risky as it can generate exceptions at any time because of multiple reasons mostly at the time of environment migration.

SSIS gives you a better solution. you can use expression task for extracting the date time part from the feed file name and comparing it with the current date time.

This would be easier as well as hassle free.

Hope, this would help you

Comment: You make a good point but it should really be a comment as this isn't actually an answer